# Long email address are not displayed entirely in the user page, thus can't be copied

Tags: bug, status-declined

I have the habit of adding a long random string at the end my email address. One use case is to manage several identities with only email address (the string after the + sign is ignored). In my own info box (user page), the column where the email address is displayed is not wide enough. The address is actually in the DOM, but there is no way to copy it easily from the page using mouse and keyboard.

Comment: What is the bug that you are reporting?  Aren't email addresses supposed to be private anyway?

Comment: Do you often forget your own email address and need to copy it from your SO profile? Sounds like an unusual case not worth optimizing for...

Comment: @CodyGray Not my own email address, but the part after the plus, if you had read my question. The bug I'm reporting is in the title of the question.

Comment: Click in the textbox, hit home if you aren't at the start, hold the shift down, hit end, then ctrl-copy.  Not a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hit "edit" and copy the whole thing from the textbox there.

We're in the process of redesigning parts of the user profile right now, but I can't promise we'll accommodate this very narrow edge case in the end.

Comment: A triple click did the trick for me. Double click doesn't word because of the "+", and drag select doesn't work either.  What do you mean "copy email address" ?

Comment: @user3585425 My bad there - forgot we don't actually turn emails into links when folks are looking at their own profile.