# Lengthly email address hidden by the 'About' box

Tags: support, bug, design

I've noticed this design bug for a while, but have never done much about it.
An issue with the design exists where if a user has a lengthy email address, the About box will partially hide it:

[image]
*(my public email address, not private [so's the other one in that screenshot, too])*

I realise that this is an edge case that affects *very* few users, but it exists for users who have a long email address by default or use a company email (like my own).

I thought I'd report this so if some day in the distant future it can be fixed. I'm calling it a design change request, not a bug report as such, because a bug it is not.

I read [Long email address are not displayed entirely in the user page, thus can't be copied](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260620/long-email-address-are-not-displayed-entirely-in-the-user-page-thus-cant-be-co) which is *extremely* related, but my bugfix request is associated with aesthetics and not the ability to copy the email address.

Although Anna Lear does say

> We're in the process of redesigning parts of the user profile right now.

There haven't been many changes to it since that post.

I propose a bugfix where emails over 36 characters long are sanitized, for example:

[image]

is sanitized to this:

[image]

Comment: Plus, no one else can see the email *in order* to copy it, so changing for that seems a bit unimportant.

Comment: Well they completely removed the email from the [new User Profile](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/255735/%CA%8E%C7%9D%CA%9Euo%C9%AF%C9%B9%C7%9Dq%CA%8E%C9%94) so.. there's that.

Comment: Yeah, this is pretty much fixed in the new profile layout. The place it will appear (only for moderators) will have like 4x as much room as it does there.

Comment: Should this have been on the StackExchange meta rather than this one?

Comment: This issue has since been fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed with the new profile design.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a matter of one property if I am not wrong

```
overflow:hidden
```

Comment: This wouldn't fix the issue.